# Extract text ignoring a pattern using regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can  I extract text beside the required pattern `<.>`, here's an example:

```
string = 'this is good < U+0097 > never end . < U+0093 > gift,<U+0094 > said . < U+0093 > test . < U+0093 > time , 
         with,<U+0094 > said boys . gave answer , Naresh Hembrom , 
         sitting crosslegged charpoy outside home , .'
```

I've tried something like, but it didn't gave me required output.

```
import re   
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', ' ', string)
```

Required Output:

```
string = 'this is good never end . gift, said. test. time, with, said boys. gave answer, 
          Naresh Hembrom, sitting crosslegged charpoy outside home, .'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I solved it.

```
import re

string = 'this is good < U+0097 > never end . < U+0093 > gift,<U+0094 > said . < U+0093 > test . < U+0093 > time , with,<U+0094 > said boys . gave answer , Naresh Hembrom , sitting crosslegged charpoy outside home , .'

regString = re.sub(r'<(.*?)>','',string)
print (regString)
```

The only thing to note though is that you will not have consistent spacing. You can mess with this regex and add a couple similar to this to achieve what ever you need though.

Feel free to comment what you need and I can help.

Answer (score 0):

`re.sub` returns a string. Try:

```
new_str = re.sub(r'<[^>]*>', '', string)
print(new_str)
```